# How to create grouped barchart in R

Tags: r, csv, bar-chart

I wanted to create a grouped  bar chart in R. However, the code I am currently used is creating a stacked bar chart. I want two bars for each day of the week. One bar showing first row of data and another bar showing second row of data. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

```
#  Sample CSV data
x <- read.csv(text="month, mon, tues, wed, thurs, fri, sat, sun
  9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 2
  9, 1, 6, 8, 1, 1, 2, 3")


library(ggplot2)
# x <- read.csv("checkinlobby.csv")
y <- data.matrix(x)
barplot(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

1st)Create a new column that will allow us to pass it to the fill argument.

2nd) Change the data from wide to long to make it easier for ggplot.

3rd) Make the day variable a factor and reorder it

4th) Plot using position = "dodge"

```
library(tidyverse)

#  Sample CSV data
x <- read.csv(text="month, mon, tues, wed, thurs, fri, sat, sun
              9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 2
              9, 1, 6, 8, 1, 1, 2, 3")


##
graph <- x %>% mutate(rows = 1:nrow(x)) %>%
  gather(day, measure, -month, -rows) %>%
  mutate(day = factor(day,
  levels = c("mon","tues","wed","thurs", "fri", "sat","sun"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = measure, fill = as.character(rows))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")

graph
```